# Detect stream's Writable last chunk

Tags: node.js, node-streams

I've created a `Writable` stream hooked to a large pipeline in our system that writes to the database after `BUFFER_SIZE` chunks (objects) are received.

```
getStream() {
    const buffer = [];

    const stream = new Writable({
        objectMode: true,
        async write(chunk,enc,next) {
            buffer.push(chunk);
            if( buffer.length > BUFFER_SIZE ) {
                await insertToDB(buffer);
            }
            next();
        }
    });

    stream.on('finish', async () => {
        // insert last batch?
        if( buffer.length ) {
            await insertToDB(buffer);
        }
    });

    return stream;
}

async consumer() {
    await pipeline(...largePipeline, getStream());
    closeAll();
}
```

This works ok, but the problem I have is that the `on('finish', ...)` event handler is called too late, after `closeAll()` has been called in the `consumer()` function.

*Is there a way for the `write()` method to know it just received the last* `chunk`? That way I could flush the buffer before calling the last `next()` and everything would be in sync.

**Please, note** that in this codebase there's a very strict separation between the pipeline, consumer and writer and I can't and won't exchange promises, flags or state checks between these components. The Writable stream is a unit on it's own! I'm looking for the way Node Streams solve this issue with buffered writes, there must be a way to check that `Writable` stream is being called last and wait for it to be really done, but I just can't grok it.

Comment: How are you using `await pipe`?  Does `pipe` return a promise?

Comment: Sorry, it should read `pipeline` from the stream promises library, which returns a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,  I've found the correct way to do this, Node Streams call a `final(next)` method when the data is exhausted, that's where you're supposed to finish-up your writing before "releasing" the stream:

```js
getStream() {
    let buffer = [];

    return new Writable({
        objectMode: true,
        async write(chunk,enc,next) {
            buffer.push(chunk);
            if( buffer.length > BUFFER_SIZE ) {
                await insertToDB(buffer);
            }
            next();
        },
        async final(next) {
            // insert last batch?
            if( buffer.length ) {
                await insertToDB(buffer);
                buffer = [];
            }
            next();
        }

    });
}

async consumer() {
    await pipeline(...largePipeline, getStream());
    closeAll();
}
```

I've also found out that the `writev()` function is the far superior way to write buffered blocks, instead of implementing your own buffer in a `Writable` stream:

```js
getStream() {
    return new Writable({
        objectMode: true,
        highWaterMark: BUFFER_SIZE,
        async writev(chunks, next) {
            await insertToDB( chunks.map( chunk => chunk.chunk ) );
            next();
        }
    });
}
```

It makes use of the `highWaterMark` configuration setting with the number of chunk objects to send you each time, which allows Node to better control backpressuring for the complete stream pipeline and simplifies your `Writable` design.